# Why was Not a Real Question deleted?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta

I posted [an answer](https://stackapps.com/a/8935/79306) on [Not a Real Question's Stack Apps post](https://stackapps.com/q/1369/79306) and shortly after, the entire post was deleted by [animuson](https://stackapps.com/users/1671/animuson).  I'm not sure why it was deleted, it seems on-topic because it is related to the Stack Exchange network.  Why was it deleted?

I'll provide a series of screenshots (because it won't fit in one):

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

[image: Screenshot 4]

Comment: screenshot for us, mere mortals of stackapps?

Comment: @OlegValter Technically I'm a mortal too, just a mortal who happened to post an answer so can view it anyway... but I've edited in screenshots.

Comment: Thanks! Huh, weird, balpha were an employee of SE up till 2019, btw, and the game is still  listed in their profile (however, it results in a server error on land, maybe that played a role).

Comment: @OlegValter I'm confused too, maybe I'll try to find animuson in chat and ask them.

Comment: What's really strange is that this shows up as a linked question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have posted the 4th answer that confirmed the app no longer worked. The first answer that came to the same conclusion was posted in 2014.

If you have nothing new to add to an Q/A, please refrain from bumping a Q/A with a new answer. It would have sufficed to upvote an existing answer that said the same.

I haven't checked with Animuson but I assume his reasoning for deleting was: *This app is not going to come back to life in the next 6 to 8 weeks. It has lost its value. Deletion is the best option.*

I leave it to him to confirm, deny or offer a different reasoning.

FWIW: I've closed so far one or two questions for abandoned apps or scripts with a custom close reason to prevent new answers but leave them as *inspiration* for creators that are looking for ideas. I'll check with the team first to see if we want to do the same here, meaning the question will be undeleted and closed instead.

Comment: You are correct. On Meta we've always had a policy of just deleting things if the app/script/whatever they pointed to no longer exists, leaving closure for things that still "exist" but are broken and not maintained anymore. If you think there is value in leaving up a post about something nobody can track down ever again because it's been offline for years, feel free. :)